# Obtener datos desde un controlador en Laravel en Vue Js e interactuar con ellos.

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuex

Estoy intentando traer datos desde un controlador de Laravel a Vue JS.

```
   data() {
    return {
        article: undefined
    }
    },
    created() {
    this.$http.get('article/' + this.$route.params.id +  '/edit?include=category,tags')
        .then((response) => {
            this.article = response.data.data
        })
       },
```

El tema es que yo no quiero obtener esos datos para mostrarlos en la vista, 
yo quiero tener esos datos para interactuar con ellos en el mismo method. Más concrétamente, para hacer una capa en Leatfet de marcadores con los campos latitud y longitud de la tabla Articles.

```
       method(){
       getcapas(){
       //Código Leatfet
       var articles = this.$http.get('article/' + this.$route.params.id +  '/edit?include=category,tags')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data.data
        })
        }

        //Código Leatfet con los datos de la tabla articles
```

Cuando hago un console.log de la variable articles, me sale lo siguiente:

```
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]...
[[PromiseValue]]= array(4) /*Con todos los valores que necesito.
```

**¿Como podría obtener los datos desde [[PromiseValue]] en el mismo method?**

He estado investigando pero no he encontrado la forma de sacar esos datos y no he encontrado nada.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
created() {
    var article;
    this.$http.get('article/' + this.$route.params.id +  '/edit?include=category,tags')
        .then((response) => {
            article = response.data.data
        });
    console.log(article);
```

},

Intentando asignar a this.article dentro del **get** no accedera a las propiedades de tu data, por eso creo una variable en el mismo ambito que el **get** y le asigno el valor dentro del **then**

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya lo había intentado, aunque dentro de method(). Pero en los dos casos, la variable devuelve 'undefined'.

Comment: Es como si hubiera que esperar la respuesta de Promise, haciendo un CallBack o algo parecido

Answer (score 0):

Al final opté por pintar los markers dentro del promise, aunque no creo que sea muy buena práctica.

```
    this.$http.get('articlesmap')
    .then((response) => {
      var articles = response.data.data


      articles.forEach((feature) => {
      console.log(feature);
      var coords = [feature.longitude,feature.latitude]
      L.marker(coords).bindPopup("<a href='http://localhost:8000/articles/"+feature.slug+"'>"+feature.title+"</a>").addTo(map);
      });

    });
```